# typescript install error Unexpected token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, installation

I'm getting this error after installing an AWS package(@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb)
into my typescript project

```
js\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-dynamodb\dist-cjs\protocols\Aws_json1_0.js:3541
        ClientRequestToken: input.ClientRequestToken ?? (0, uuid_1.v4)(),
                                                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
```

This is the set up for my project.(tsconfig.ts)
`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",        // path to output directory
        "sourceMap": true,          // allow sourcemap support
        "strictNullChecks": true,   // enable strict null checks as a best practice
        "module": "commonjs",       // specify module code generation
        "allowJs": true,            // allow a partial TypeScript and JavaScript codebase
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@config/*": ["config/*"],
            "@common/*": ["test/common/*"],
            "@models/*": ["test/models/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "./"
    ]
}
```

`

This is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.218.0",
  "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "^3.218.0",
"ts-node": "^8.10.1",
"tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
"typescript": "^3.8.3"
}
```

tried changing the typescript version

Overall goal is to have the typescript error away

Comment: Set your target to a lower version of JS for your compiler output.

Comment: What version of node/npm are you on?

Comment: node: 10.15
npm: 6.4.1

Comment: @JaredSmith i tried setting the target to es5. same error

Comment: @FrancisAde node 10 hit end of life *five years ago* (April of 2018). Upgrade to a newer version of node. That will *probably* fix your problem, at least your immediate one.

Comment: But longer term... well, you can run with old versions of things as long as you don't mind the gaping security holes. But as soon as you try to add a new dependency it isn't going to work with all of your ancient packages/runtime. You will need to budget in maintenance time to periodically upgrade your environment and dependencies. It sucks to have to do that when a system has been running without problems, and in a perfect world people would be less cavalier about breaking things and you wouldn't need to, but that's not the world we live in. This is what happens when you don't.

Comment: Also correction: node 10 came out 4/2018. It was EOL'd 2 years ago. Still.